# How to navigate from ObjC file to swift file in objC project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My project name is `ObjCSwift`. After creating the project, I create a new swift file `SecondViewController.swift` with `xib`.

I have imported `#import "ObjCSwift-Swift.h"` in `AppDelegate.m` and  this is my code for `ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ObjCSwift-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController* controller;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)goToSwiftAction:(id)sender {
    _controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
//    _controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
_controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_controller animated:true];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

The project runs successfully with no warning. But when I tap the button `goToSwiftAction`, the method is called but the view is not navigating.

I also set the **Embedded Code Contains Swift Code** to **YES**.

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Does your ViewController.m has a NavigationController? If no, you need NavigationController to push and pop views.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. still not working.

Comment: I also set `@objc class SecondViewController: UIViewController {` and am using Xcode 7.3

Comment: import this #import "ObjCSwift-Swift.h" in bridging header and try

Comment: No, i got error. `file not found`. Actually if i create a function in second view controller, I can call it from my objc controller. but unable to navigate to that page.

Answer (score 1):

try this

**From storyboard to xib**

```
SecondViewController *viewController=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; // ensure once your nib name is correctly or not.

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if it is In case of underwith in NavigatinController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Actually i tried the above step but not worked. My mistake was trying to navigate from storyboard to xib. So i removed the storyboard and used xib on both cases. It worked!!!

Comment: welcome bro, if my answer is useful please accept the answer]

Answer (score 1):

This one helps to me

Navigate Objective C to Swift Controller

on your objective C Class use below for navigation to swift controller

```
YourSwiftViewController *Obj = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"swiftIdentifier"];

[self presentViewController:Obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This image helps how to set identifier in storyboard

[image]

Similar Navigate Swift to Objective C Controller

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let obj : YourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerIdentifier") as! YourViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```